# Пользовательская xml десериализация в Unity для Android

Tags: unity3d, serialize

Здравствуйте, пишу игру на Unity под Android в качестве дипломной работы. Возникла потребность создавать в редакторе некоторые структуры и сохранять их в файлы. А во время выполнения программы десериализовать их и использовать.

На ПК(при запуске с Unity) все работает отлично, но в скомпилированном виде для Android выдает ошибку о несуществующем пути.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для получения имен файлов использую `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);` Сам `path`, сначала, вписывал константой, начиная с папки Assets. Так же, пробовал создавать `path` с помощью `Aplication.dataPath`. Все та же ошибка.

Читал на разных форумах, что для Android все файлы пакуются в "архив", поэтому нельзя получить доступ к файлам напрямую.

Как можно это обойти? Или как по другому сериализовать/десериализовать структуры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлы которые собираются из проекта в билд превращаются в **бинарники**, и достать их по какому-либо пути нет возможности. Этот способ возможен, если только файл создавать собственно на самом устройстве. Но все же можно использовать свои файлы, если поместить их в папку **Resources** и загружать **Resources.Load** как **TextAsset**, данные из него можно получить либо как строку(string), либо как массив байт. Ну и десериализовывать.

p.s. Вообще нет как таковой надобности в использовании ручного xml, у юнити есть своя сериализация, которую можно использовать на любом классе, нужно лишь добавить **[system.Serializable]**. И прикрутить к какому-либо скрипту(все monobehaviour с public переменными или [SerializeField] для private автоматически сериализуются) на сцене. Можно сделай Editor окно для удобства заполнения данных. Юнити все сделает за вас, только заполняй данными. Но если данных ну очень много, то только базу данных делать(sql там или еще что).

Comment: Похоже, TextAsset должен подойти для моих целей. Сегодня проверю и отпишусь. Спасибо)